# JavaScript - Concatenating 2 parameters inside a function not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to parse 2 numbers as parameters of  the function `saveQuestion` function but it is not working.

```
$("#questionRow")
.append('<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="saveQuestion'
        + addSectionCount + '" value="Save question ' 
        + addSectionCount + '" onclick="saveQuestion(' 
        + addOpSectionCount + '\',\'' addSectionCount + ')" ></div>');
```

Comment: try registering a proper callback function with `.on('click', f)`, instead of passing an `onclick` attribute - it'll be far less brittle!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be far less brittle and avoid the problem altogether if you just used jQuery to register a proper callback function instead of using '90s style inline event handlers:

```
$('<input type="submit" />')
    .attr('id', 'saveQuestion' + addSectionCount)
    .val('Save question ' + addSectionCount)
    .on('click', function() {
        saveQuestion(addOpSectionCount, addSectionCount);
    })
    .appendTo('#questionRow')'
```

Note also the other uses of jQuery functions to avoid the use of string concatenation within the HTML string.

NB: I've reversed the `append` so that the chained `.on` call applies to the newly created element, not to `#questionRow`.

NB 2: I'd normally use `$('<el>', {id: ..., val: ...})` but ISTR that MSIE has (had?) an issue with that syntax on input elements.

Comment: Thanks for your help. it looks good but when i do it, the button is not working and no error is displayed on the console

Answer (score 2):

As Luca mentioned, you were missing a + operator. You also didn't add enough single quotes into saveQuestion's arguments for the way you formatted it. This should work:

```
$("#questionRow")
   .append('<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="saveQuestion'
       + addSectionCount + '" value="Save question ' 
       + addSectionCount + '" onclick="saveQuestion(\'' 
       + addOpSectionCount + '\',\'' + addSectionCount + '\')" ></div>');
   });
```

As others have mentioned, since you're using jQuery anyway, you should attach a click event handler to the input using jQuery:

```
$('#saveQuestion'+addSectionCount).on('click', function() {
   // do stuff
});
```

Comment: My first attempt at an answer looked like your second example, but then I realised that was incorrectly adding the click handler to the whole row, not just the new `<input>` element

Comment: I'm also pretty sure he _doesn't_ want those extra quotes, as those'll just pass the string literal `'addSectionCount'` instead of the value of the variable with that name.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the jQuery callback with the correct ID. As for passing string literals, I assume he wants to pass the values as strings, since he used single quotes in his original code. His code resulted in `onclick="saveQuestion(',')"`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you missed a + operator near the end of your code

```
$("#questionRow")
    .append('<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="saveQuestion'
        + addSectionCount + '" value="Save question ' 
        + addSectionCount + '" onclick="saveQuestion(' 
        + addOpSectionCount + '\',\''
        + addSectionCount + ')" ></div>');
```